# Moodle - Mudar estrutura da home de acordo com o usuario e manter diferente em relação as outras paginas

Tags: moodle

Boa tarde,

Minha dúvida é o seguinte:

Preciso mudar a estrutura da home somente da home, em vez de deixar 3 colunas (navegação,conteúdo e aside-right) vou deixar apenas uma coluna que é do conteúdo, gostaria de saber se tem como eu deixar SOMENTE a home com essa estrutura e nas demais paginas internas eu manter a estrutura padrão de 3 colunas.

Outra dúvida:

Preciso criar duas homes, na estrutura citada acima, porem cada home vai exibir um conteúdo diferente de acordo com o login do usuário, ex: ADMIN vai ter acesso a uma home e Educador vai ter acesso a outra home, é possível? Alguma ideia de como fazer?

Estou conhecendo o moodle agora, ja criei um child theme e estou modificando ele, mas essas modificações acima achei mais complicada.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Veja o arquivo `config.php` do seu `theme` e configura conforme sua necessidade.

Tenho um `theme` que configurei da seguinte forma:

```
// The site home page.
    'frontpage' => array(
        'file' => 'frontpage.php',
        'regions' => array('side-post', 'middle'),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-post',
        'options' => array('nonavbar' => true),
    ),

// My dashboard page.
    'mydashboard' => array(
        'file' => 'columns2.php',
        'regions' => array('side-post'),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-post',
        'options' => array('langmenu' => true),
    ),

// Server administration scripts.
    'admin' => array(
        'file' => 'columns2.php',
        'regions' => array('side-post'),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-post',
    ),
```

dessa maneira você poderá configurar sua página inicial.

Em relação a segunda dúvida, você poderá resolver utilizando o arquivo `renderers.php`, fiz algo mais ou menos assim no meu tema:

```
protected function render_user_menu(custom_menu $menu) {
        global $CFG, $USER, $DB, $OUTPUT;

        $addlangmenu = true;
        $addmessagemenu = true;

        if (!isloggedin() || isguestuser()) {
            $addmessagemenu = false;
        }
        if (!$CFG->messaging) {
            $addmessagemenu = false;
        } else {
            // Check whether or not the "popup" message output is enabled
            // This is after we check if messaging is enabled to possibly save a DB query.
            $popup = $DB->get_record('message_processors', array('name' => 'popup'));
            if (!$popup) {
                $addmessagemenu = false;
            }
        }
...
}
```